# Can't start mongodb by launchctl on OS X Yosemite (10.10.2)

Tags: macos, homebrew, mongodb

I've installed mongodb 2.4 via homebrew:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/mongodb24
```

Then I've made a simlink to the config provided by homebrew:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb24/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

This file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mongodb24/bin/mongod</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
  <key>HardResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>1024</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>1024</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And now I'm trying to start it and get error:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb24/2.4.12/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24.plist: Operation not permitted
```

Seems like there is some problem with permissions. But I'm not sure. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved that problem by using [brew services](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew).
Remove symlink first:

```
$ rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24.plist
```

Install brew services:

```
$ brew tap gapple/services
```

Start mongodb:

```
$ brew services start mongodb24
==> Successfully started `mongodb24` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb24)
```

That's it!

**UPDATE:**

Actually, this happens because of tmux. When you do this inside of a tmux session:

```
$ brew services start redis
/Users/schfkt/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist: Operation not permitted
==> Successfully started `redis` (label: homebrew.mxcl.redis)

$ brew services list
Warning: No user-space services controlled by `brew services` running...
```

You get the same result: "Operation not permitted". And redis of course is not started.

But everything works fine when you run the same commands **not** inside of a tmux session:

```
$ brew services start redis
==> Successfully started `redis` (label: homebrew.mxcl.redis)

$ brew services list
redis      started    82912 /Users/schfkt/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Comment: You can also use brew services within tmux if you've installed reattach-to-user-namespace `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace` 
Then you should be able to run `reattach-to-user-namespace brew services start redis` without leaving tmux More details can be found here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/using-tmux-and-pbpaste-pbcopy-and-launchctl